# How do I copy a row of values to another tab if a specific criterion is fulfilled?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, search, vlookup

I have two tabs with identical tables except one of them is supposed to contain those records that matches one of two values in one of the columns.

What I want is that whenever I add a new row to the first tab, it should automatically show up in the other tab provided it fulfills this criterion.

The content of the column based on which I want this table to be filtered is regular text, either "consulant" or "invoice". So if a record is assigned to a consultant I want it to be copied over to the other tab in the spreadsheet.

I tried to do this by applying an advanced filter, but since I'm working on Excel 2010 it wouldn't let me copy the result of the filter outside the active tab.

Can anyone help me with this? I'm still an excel newbie, so I would prefer a solution that doesn't involve VBA so I can understand it and adjust for myself.